# In Javascript, is it possible to communicate to workers while inside while-loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, web-worker, callstack

I have a recursive calculation, which I handle using a manual call stack.

```
var stack = initialListOfTasks();

while (stack.length > 0) {
    var todo = stack.shift();

    performTask(stack, todo);
}
```

The function `performTask()` adds new tasks to the stack and this works fine.

The individual functions could be done independently of one another, which is why, in attempt to make the code run more quickly, I would like to distribute the tasks in the call stack to a number of workers. The problem is, from the while-loop I use to go through the tasks I don't know how to communicate with workers.

Possibly naively, I tried the following for example.

```
var stack = initialListOfTasks();

var n_workers = navigator.hardwareConcurrency;
var n_workers_in_use = 0;

while (stack.length > 0 || n_workers_in_use > 0) {
    if (stack.length > 0 && n_workers_in_use < n_workers) {
        var todo = stack.shift();

        var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
        worker.postMessage(todo);
        n_workers_in_use++;

        worker.onmessage = function(obj) {
            var new_tasks = obj.data;
            stack = stack.concat(new_tasks);

            n_workers_in_use--;
            worker.terminate();
        };
    }
}
```

This creates an infinite loop, because `n_workers_in_use` is increased, but never decreased because the `onmessage` function is never triggered. I also tried opening a number of `n_workers` of workers outside of the while-loop and posting messages to it inside the while-loop, but this does not work either. It is only after I manually exit the while-loop, I can see that that the `onmessage` function is triggered.

Is there a way to get this `onmessage` to trigger and change the values of stack and `n_workers_in_use` from inside the while-loop? Or is there maybe a way of doing this without a while-loop? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can communicate **to** the Workers, but you can't receive their response. That is because the messageevent is handled in a future task. To do what you wish you could convert your code to an async function, and then `await` a single message event: `await new Promise((resolve, reject) => worker.addEventListener("message', (obj) => {(...); resolve();} , { once: true }));`. However, in your case I can only advise you to change completely your model. Starting a new Worker is an HEAVY operation. It costs a lot of CPU work and consumes a lot of memory. You should never have a one-shot Worker.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will toy around a little bit with these async functions to see if I can get it to work. This was a naive example. If I get it to work, I would start up the workers before the while-loop, reuse them many times inside the while-loop, and then terminate them after the while-loop. Do you think that would be a good approach?

Comment: If you don't think they can be resused to something else, then yes that would be a better approach, but the best one would be to start just as many workers as `navigator.hardwareConcurrency - 1`, keep them alive, and make them handle many tasks, not just that one.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, that would seem the best approach to me too. In the meanwhile I have been trying, but I don't get the async function to work properly. Let's say, in the while loop, I call this async function `async function testFunc() { var resolution = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve("resolved"); }); console.log(resolution); }`, then the console log still only happens after I escape the while loop. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Your while loop itself must be in the async function and await all the promises, but tou'll lose the parallel processing benefice doing so

Comment: Ah right. I managed to do it like that. Parallel processing can still be achieved. I distribute tasks to the workers and list their promises. Then I await an async/await equivalent of `Promise.race()`. When any of the promises is resolved I remove the promise from the promises list, I check which worker is finished and immediately give it a new task and add the promise to the list. Then run the while-loop as long as `promises.length > 0`. So this works fine, thanks for the help!